# How to get Delta from a row HTML string in flutter_quill?

Tags: flutter

Hallow! I need to insert HTML from server to flutter_quill editor, but how to do it? Maybe is it unable thing... Thanks for any answers!

I can make a new document from Delta or from JSON only

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know flutter_quill don't support the html data types. I think it can provide data in delta, plain text & json formats only.

But you can use [quill_html_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/quill_html_editor) library to use the html together with quill editor in flutter. The usage is almost like flutter_quill with more focus on html type content.

To set the html content to editor you just have to set the html string in the controller

```
 await controller.setText(text);
```

Give it a try. May be it can fulfil your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But another editor isn't fit for us...

Comment: As far as I can see online. There isn't any html to quill converter in flutter or dart. Some people claims to do this using some nodejs library. But this can only be done on server & come with few limitations. See this https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1240#issuecomment-1103441862